# How do i export an ARM template correctly from Azure?

Tags: azure

I have already installed my azure environment with a VM, a storage account and a data base server, and it works fine, but now i want to export the ARM template in order to automate the whole proccess to my customers. The problem is that when exporting this message shows up:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhXF4.png)

So the question is how do i export an ARM template correctly from Azure with all my resources without having to do much fixing my final template?

Comment: I'm on the ARM Deployments team at Microsoft, which owns Export Template. If you're happy to share either a correlationId, or the detailed error messages (click the "See error details" arrow), I can help investigate whether this is a case of missing schema availability, or a problem with the RP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is expected. some resource types cannot be exported. you'd have to take a look at the api definition and use that to export those (say at resources.azure.com)

Comment: Ok so i can use those API requests within my ARM template directly to create the missing resources?

Comment: no, you can look at the api definition of the resources that it failed to export and add them to the template

Comment: It is pretty weird, the failed resources don't show up in the Azure resource Explorer and are not recognizable or usefull for my deployment, so what sould i do?, ignore them or add them manually?

Comment: what are those? thats somewhat unlikely\impossible

Comment: The resources are these :-Microsoft.Sql/servers/backupLongTermRetentionVaults, Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/workloadGroups, Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies, Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices, Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices. And as i said, i do not use them at all

Comment: then you dont have to include them in your template

Answer (score 1):

Simple: use bicep. Azure Resource Manager's transpiler (it's a sweeter syntax that solves your needs)

In Bicep the directive you're looking for in your Azure Resource Manager "ARM" template is keyword "existing"

https://github.com/Azure/bicep/blob/main/docs/tutorial/05-loops-conditions-existing.md

keyword "existing" lets you reference a resource without a complete definition.

Otherwise you need to provide the entire ARM definition for the object.

Answer (score 0):

Export failures per resource type occur when a given resource types schema is not available. We are looking into how we can autogenerate schemas for Azure resource providers and onboarding them to this new process, improving the overall success of the Export Template API.